# Rollup preserveModulesRoot not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollupjs

I feel like the `preserveModulesRoot` option while using `preserveModules` does not work as it should. Let's say I have a `src/index.ts` and a bunch of `src/components/CompXYZ.tsx` files. What I expect to happen with the preserve modules and root set to `src` is for my build to look like this:

```
dist
-- index.js
-- index.map.js
-- index.d.ts
-- components
---- CompA.js
---- CompA.map.js
---- CompA.d.ts
---- CompB.js
---- CompB.map.js
---- CompB.d.ts
```

But what actually happens is that the `src` prefix is stripped only from the `input.ts` file and no other so the build ends up looking like this:

```
dist
-- index.js
-- index.map.js
-- index.d.ts
-- components
---- CompA.d.ts
---- CompB.d.ts
-- src
---- components
------ CompA.js
------ CompA.map.js
------ CompB.js
------ CompB.map.js
```

So it looks like `preserveModulesRoot` only affect modules mentioned in `input` option but if I was to manually write out all the modules one by one, I can just place them where I want instead of using the `preserveModulesRoot`. What's the point of this setting if not to set root for all additional modules created with `preserveModules` enabled?

Here is my `rollup.config.js`

```js
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
        preserveModules: true,
        preserveModulesRoot: 'src',
    },
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        typescript(),
        postcss(),
        image(),
    ],
};
```

Comment: Have you found the solution to it? I ran into the same problem

Comment: Sadly can't quite remember if I came up with something working but eventually I went with completely different solution.

Answer (score 2):

I dealt with the same thing when moving my build scripts from the root of a monorepo to a package within it. I think the issue might be due to this section of code: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/5a5391971d695c808eed0c5d7d2c6ccb594fc689/src/Chunk.ts#L460-L464

Without the complete path:

```
              preserveModules: true,
              preserveModulesRoot: `packages/${displayName}/src`
```

yields a `dist/` folder like this:

[image: without complete path]

With the complete path we want removed:

```
                preserveModules: true,
                preserveModulesRoot: path.join(process.env.PROJECT_CWD, `packages/${displayName}/src`)
```

yields a `dist/` folder like this (which seems like it's more like what you were expecting):

[image: with complete path]

FYI: `displayName` prop is coming from the package.json of each individual package.

Comment: This worked for me (I was using workspaces too), besides, in order to achieve a direct import in the client, eg:  
{ myComponen1, myComponent2} from '@myDomain/myPackage'; 

I also needed to update the entry point in the package.json     

"module": "lib/src/index.js",